# Event Management within a GUI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to structure a GUI and manage events, I decided to use jquery also saw the overall complexity of what I'm going to build.

The structure is divided into three sections, a global section, a dynamic section and a section for results. The global section contains the other two sections.

The sample html is the following:

```
<section id="global">
 <ul id="wrapper">
  <li>Name
   <ul class="box1">
    <li>Name
     ..and so on
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Name
   <ul class="box2>
    <li>Name
     ..and so on
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <section id="result"></section>
</section>
```

I want to know what is the best method to handle events inside my structure Whereas:

- The dynamic section is formed by a series of lists in hierarchy
- The result section is updated every time you select a list (.box) in the dynamic section (also using ajax)
- Section results in turn will have to manage events (eg. Data filter)

I'm coding a bit 'of objects and now I have something like:

```
function Box(selector) {
 var self = this;
 var box = $(selector);

 this.getName = function()
 this.bindClick = function()
 this.toggle = function()
 this.showChilds = function() 
 this.hideChilds = function()
 this.defaultLevel = function() 
 this.highlight = function()
 //etc
};

function Wrapper() {
 var self = this;
 this.wrapper = $("#wrapper");
 this.levels = [];

 this.activate = function() {
   this.wrapper.find("li").each(
   function() {
    var el = new Box(this);
    el.bindClick();

    //add all box to wrapper
    self.levels.push(el);
   }
  );
 };

 this.updateWrapper = function(data) {
  //code that update the result section
 };

 function load(boxName) {
  $.ajax(
   {
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (json) {
     self.updateWrapper(json);
    }
   }
  );
 };
};


//call on DOM ready
// the DOM is ready
var w = new Wrapper();
w.activate();
```

My greater concern is the fact of having to manage events through the wrapper object (which in theory should coordinate a bit 'all over the script) but in fact this object does not trigger any event.

How do I intercept which box has been clicked in the UI inside the wrapper object? I'm right? best practices? suggestions, doubt?

Thank you

Comment: This is far too broad. Please narrow down problem(s) to specific code related issues. As it stands right now it is not clear what problems you are having.

Comment: How do I intercept which box has been clicked in the UI inside the wrapper object? thanks

Comment: `this` inside a jQuery event handler is the element that event occured on

Comment: so as oppose, how do I send the result of the click to the wrapper object that should update the result section?

Comment: Within the click handler would have something like `Wrapper.doSomething()`

Comment: I can't, beacuse the click event should be trigger by a box inside the wrapper and I think I have to work starting from the wrapper. As you can see the wrapper have an array (levels) that contains all the boxes, so I should find which box has been clicked and than fire up the event that update the result section.. hope is clear

Comment: I think you are making this far more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: I know I can be more direct and bind a click for each boxes that update the result section, but this is not what I was looking for.. there's many other function I need to manage in this widget.